# My python2.7 suddenly stopped working, complaining about a python3.5 script

Tags: python, python-2.7

My python27 and python35/36 installations were working alright up to now.
Now suddenly, when I run python2 on my terminal, all I get is :

$ python2

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 182
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is python2 trying to access python3 site-packages script? How can I fix this?
(Ubuntu 16.04 OS)

edit: That's all the output. If I use the verbose switch:

```
$ python2 -v
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 182
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
# clear __builtin__._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.exitfunc
# clear sys.exc_type
# clear sys.exc_value
# clear sys.exc_traceback
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup __main__
# cleanup[1] zipimport
# cleanup[1] signal
# cleanup[1] exceptions
# cleanup[1] _warnings
# cleanup sys
# cleanup __builtin__
# cleanup ints: 5 unfreed ints
# cleanup floats
```

Comment: Please post the entire traceback.

Comment: Are there any administrative tasks you have run on your machine prior to this issue? Installing any new packages? Updating anything?

Comment: What's the output of `type -all python2`? (Maybe omit the `-all` if your shell is not Bash.)

Comment: @tripleee $type -all python2  ->
python2 is /usr/bin/python2

Comment: What is the value of ``PYTHONPATH``? E.g. what does ``echo $PYTHONPATH`` in the terminal yield?

Comment: @C.Nivs, I'm not entirely sure, but I don't think so. I haven't updated using apt for ~two weeks. Been postponing that because of a mysterious -persisting- "Some packages cannot be  authenticated!" error when upgrading. But that's another story.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, echo $PYTHONPATH -> :/usr/lib/python3.5   ,  I use python35

Comment: That's the source of the problem, then. You are telling Python to use the 3.5 libraries. Check which script (e.g. ``.bashrc``) sets it and remove the ``PYTHONPATH`` modification from it.

Comment: How come it had been working prior to now? :/
I've been using both pythons for a long time.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi is this normal in my bashrc? 
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/lib/python3.5"
why does it append the absolute path to previous value?

Comment: This is the correct way of expanding PATH-like environment variables. *Why* this code is in your ``.bashrc``, we can at most guess.

Comment: @Shamshun: That line is *not* normal. `PYTHONPATH` is a hack, and shouldn't be set by default unless you're personally hacking in specific directories of your own personally developed modules you were too lazy to convert to installable packages (which must be fully Python 2/3 compatible if you want both to work). Comment out that line and run `unset PYTHONPATH` in existing terminals to clear it. If you didn't add that line, does someone else use your account who might have done so?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I meant why *expand* the variable, when it is supposed to be a single address. it doesn't work when I extend the variable using paths to both python versions

Comment: @ShadowRanger No, no one else does. I don't remember seeing that line either. Removing and unsetting PYTHONPATH did the trick! Thanks. Now both python2 and python3 work.

Please add an answer so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997785/my-python2-7-suddenly-stopped-working-complaining-about-a-python3-5-script?noredirect=1#comment111405516_62997785) to answer on request:

You say your `.bashrc` contains the line:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/lib/python3.5"
```

`PYTHONPATH` is a hack, and shouldn't be set by default unless you're personally hacking in specific directories of your own personally developed modules you were too lazy to convert to installable packages (which must be fully Python 2/3 compatible if you want both to work). By having `/usr/lib/python3.5` in your `PYTHONPATH` it says that *all* versions of Python (not just 3.5) should look there before they look in the default module lookup locations when `import`s are performed.

To fix, all you need to do is:

1. Comment out that line from your `.bashrc` (to prevent the problem in the future)
2. Run `unset PYTHONPATH` in existing terminals to fix the problem immediately (or just log out and back in after step 1)

Answer (score 0):

when working with multiple python versions always make sure that `PYTHOPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` are pointing on the right directories,the first should point to your python  bin folder and the second to the lib folder where the right site-packages are